# Jssor - unbinding the event

Tags: javascript, event-handling, jssor

I have a simple event handler:

```
jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_CLICK, function (slideIndex) {
    jssor_slider1.$PlayTo(slideIndex - 4, [200]);
});
```

I have a problem trying to unbding it (i need to disable it in a different function, then enable it again on callback - when ajax loads). I tried $Off, also overwriting $On handler, but can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function SliderParkEventHandler(slideIndex) {
    jssor_slider1.$PlayTo(slideIndex - 4, [200]);
}

jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_CLICK, SliderParkEventHandler);

//use following code to unbind click event
//jssor_slider1.$Off($JssorSlider$.$EVT_CLICK, SliderParkEventHandler);
```